# Android - Constraint Layout wont respect margins?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm very new to `ConstraintLayout` and I'm having trouble with margins.  I have the following `layout` file, but I'm trying to get the **`layoutNewsEventsItemImageContainer`** to have a `20dp` margin on the left, while keeping the `TextView`'s to the left of that margin.

What am I doing wrong???

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"    
    android:id="@+id/layoutNewsEventsItemContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="20dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblNewsEventsItemHeadline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/layoutNewsEventsItemImageContainer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblNewsEventsItemCopy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/layoutNewsEventsItemImageContainer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblNewsEventsItemHeadline"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblNewsEventsItemDateModified"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/layoutNewsEventsItemImageContainer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblNewsEventsItemCopy"/>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutNewsEventsItemImageContainer"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@color/BackgroundColor2"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see in the preview below, it's cutting off my Copy `TextView`.  The `TextView` should be keeping to the left of the `layoutNewsEventsItemImageContainer` and therefore wrapping to the next line.  but as you can see, no margin is being applied.

[image]

Comment: for the purpose of learning (for me as well), i'd like to reference [android documentation for constraint layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) , may you please upload a snapshot image of what your layout looks like right now?

Comment: @EvOlaNdLuPiZ preview added.

Comment: from what i see, you have three text views one after another lined up vertically, so i believe constraint layout doesn't know which one to line up next to. the question i ask is, which one does constraint layout next to? again this is at a first glance, but a better solution *imo* use relative layout to contain the textviews. then position constraint layout next to the relative layout.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As suggested, place your text views inside relative layout. This will allow your constraint layout to align next to something it knows, as opposed to aligning next to a textview that might change size and thus causing overlapping. You get predictable behavior with this.

```
<ConstraintLayout 
android:id="@+id/layoutNewsEventsItemContainer"
...

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/container_for_textview"
android:width="wrap_content"
android:height="wrap_content">
 <TextView> ...first
 <TextView> ...second
 <TextView> ...third
</RelativeLayout>

<ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutNewsEventsItemImageContainer"
    ....
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/container_for_textview"
</ConstraintLayout>

</ConstraintLayout>//NewsEventsItemContainer
```

Comment: You might consider which layout to use, but placing `RelativeLayout` in `ConstraintLayout` is always a bad solution, because of the performance and because you simply never actually need it (you can achieve everything with just `ConstraintLayout` of what you wanted to achieve by placing `RelativeLayout` in it)

Comment: please don't post without code. i'd like to see your solution and run it on my end so i can verify and validate your claim. thank you.

Comment: You should use either RelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout. There is no need for using both

Answer (score 4):

Please user below `xml` code to achieve proper result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layoutNewsEventsItemContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="20dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblNewsEventsItemHeadline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="TextViewnsd,n,snfklsdnfknkfnm,nfm,nf,mn,mfnm,sdnfm,dnf,mnsd,mfn,sdmfn,dmsnf,sdnf,nsd,fn,sdf,nms,fn,fsd"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/layoutNewsEventsItemImageContainer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblNewsEventsItemCopy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/layoutNewsEventsItemImageContainer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblNewsEventsItemHeadline" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblNewsEventsItemDateModified"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="yess"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/layoutNewsEventsItemImageContainer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblNewsEventsItemCopy" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutNewsEventsItemImageContainer"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This will help you to achieve below result using `constraint layout`

[image]

Hope this will help

Comment: the key part is switching wrap_content width with 0dp (match constraint), it won't respect margin vs the constraint layout parent otherwise

Comment: I just set the width to 0dp like below and it worked. android:layout_width="0dp"

Thanks! Your answer is quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

first of all why don't you just use an Image View for your container ? 
and check this one just edit the text view width that don't accept the margin to 0dp

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/layoutNewsEventsItemContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:padding="20dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblNewsEventsItemHeadline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/layoutNewsEventsItemImageContainer"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblNewsEventsItemCopy"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/layoutNewsEventsItemImageContainer"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblNewsEventsItemHeadline" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblNewsEventsItemDateModified"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/layoutNewsEventsItemImageContainer"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblNewsEventsItemCopy" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/layoutNewsEventsItemImageContainer"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/lblNewsEventsItemCopy"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

</ImageView>
```

Comment: because I have 3 images inside the image container.

Comment: okay my bad then just change the ImageView to ConstraintLayout and make sure to wrap the text to match constraint which will set its width to zero and that's it